# Vapor pressure in a closed box

Tags: gas, evaporation

If there is a closed box at room temperature with water inside after a certain point there will be an equilibrium condition where some water is liquid and some is vapor. So there will be a certain vapor pressure.

My question is: if there is the same box with the same water except this time there is also some other gas inside the box, will the vapor pressure be the same of the previous case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be the same if the gasses are close to being ideal, and so [Dalton's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dalton%27s_law) of partial pressure holds. While Dalton's law is only approximate, is is a *very good* approximation under most practical circumstances.

Comment: I was thinking of applying Raoult's law since the second gas will, to some degree, form a mixture with water in liquid form. I don't see how Dalton's law would be applied here.